# Image upload does not create the image in the folder only in the database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm experiencing a headache, today I had a result in my code that made me happy, I made it work it creates the UPDATE in the database even with the image upload, but the image does not create in the folder that it is (uploads/IMAGE)

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
   
   $hostname = "localhost";
   $username = "root";
   $password = "";
   $databaseName = "hmusic";
   
   $connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName);
   $artist_photo = $_POST['artist_photo'];
   
   if(isset($_FILES['artist_photo']['error'])){
            if($_FILES['artist_photo']['error'] == 0){
         
                $target_dir = "uploads/";
                
                $artist_photo = time()."_".rand(100000,10000000).rand(100000,10000000)."_".$_FILES["artist_photo"]["name"];

                $artist_photo = str_replace(" ", "_", $artist_photo);
                $artist_photo = urlencode($artist_photo);
 

                $source = $_FILES["artist_photo"]["tmp_name"];
                $destinatin = $target_dir.$artist_photo;
                
                 if(move_uploaded_file($source, $destinatin)){
                     
                 }else{
                    $artist_photo = "";
                 }
            }
    }
    
   $artist_id = $_POST['artist_id'];
   $artist_name = $_POST['artist_name'];
   $artist_biography = $_POST['artist_biography'];
   $artist_social_fb = $_POST['artist_social_fb'];
   $artist_social_ig = $_POST['artist_social_ig'];
   $artist_social_tw = $_POST['artist_social_tw'];
           
   // mysql query to Update data
   $query = "
   UPDATE artist
      SET artist_name = '".$artist_name."'
        , artist_biography = '".$artist_biography."'
        , artist_social_fb = '".$artist_social_fb."'
        , artist_social_ig = '".$artist_social_ig."'
        , artist_social_tw = '".$artist_social_tw."'
        , artist_photo = '".$artist_photo."' 
    WHERE artist_id = $artist_id
    ";
   
   $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
   
   if($result)
   {
       echo 'Data Updated';
   }else{
       echo 'Data Not Updated';
   }
   mysqli_close($connect);
}
?>
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<form action="#" method="post">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="artist_id">Artist ID</label>
                <input type="text" name="artist_id" class="form-control" id="artist_id"  placeholder="Enter artist id"> 
              </div> 
              
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="artist_name">Artist Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="artist_name" class="form-control" id="artist_name"  placeholder="Enter artist name"> 
              </div>
              
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="artist_id">Artist Biography</label>
                <input type="text" name="artist_biography" class="form-control" id="artist_biography"  placeholder="Enter artist biography"> 
              </div>

              <label for="artist_photo">Artist Photo</label>
              <div style="margin-bottom: 25px;" class="file-upload">
                    <label style="background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(240, 152, 25) 0%, rgb(237, 222, 93) 51%, rgb(240, 152, 25) 100%);" for="upload" class="file-upload__label">Upload Photo Artist to <?php echo $wo['config']['msc_site_name']; ?> Music</label>
                    <input type="file" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif,image/*" name="artist_photo" class="file-upload__input" id="artist_photo"> 
             </div>
             <img style="text-align: initial;display: none;width: 170px;border-radius: 8px;" id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
             
              
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="artist_id">Artist Social Facebook</label>
                <input type="text" name="artist_social_fb" class="form-control" id="artist_social_fb"  placeholder="Enter artist name"> 
              </div>
              
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="artist_id">Artist Social Instagram</label>
                <input type="text" name="artist_social_ig" class="form-control" id="artist_social_ig"  placeholder="Enter artist name"> 
              </div>
              
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="artist_id">Artist Social Twitter</label>
                <input type="text" name="artist_social_tw" class="form-control" id="artist_social_tw"  placeholder="Enter artist name"> 
              </div>

              <button type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-primary m-t-15 waves-effect">Update Song</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Don't write sql inline like that. Use prepared statements.

Comment: Using of a php framework would help you to find a more standard way to get a more secure code. Also you would easily find tutorial to achieve this ;-)